# Haskell problem with potential workaround for empty lists

Tags: list, haskell

I defined a function that receives a data type and a list.

```
getAux :: (Ord a) => SparseArray a -> [Bool] -> (Value a)
getAux (Node x left right) index
 | length(index) == 0 = x
 | head(index) == False = getAux (left) (tail(index))
 | head(index) == True = getAux (right) (tail(index))
```

I iterate through this function passing the **tail** of ***index***
There are 3 possible returns: If the length of the list is less that or equal to 1 it returns x (the value stored in the node) If not it check the head of index and it calls getAux with the tail of index.

I tried to do a simple workaround to this issue by adding an extra element to the end of index when I call getAux. **Instead of comparing if the length of index is equal to 0 I compare it with 1**.

When I call the function I have:

```
getAux (Nodo x iz de) (num2bin(index) ++ [True])
```

The new getAux is:

```
getAux :: (Ord a) => SparseArray a -> [Bool] -> (Value a)
getAux (Node x left right) index
 | length(index) == 1 = x
 | head(index) == False = getAux (left) (tail(index))
 | head(index) == True = getAux (right) (tail(index))
```

In both cases I get an error indicating that I can't do the head of an empty list

Comment: Can you provide the defintion of `SparseArray`? Likely it has another data constructor than `Node` as well?

Comment: You say "If the length of the list is less than or equal to 1 it returns x", and then later "Instead of comparing if the length of index is equal to 0 I compare it with 1.": Don't you want to check if the length of index is 0 or 1 instead?

Comment: Can you give a concrete input which causes the error you are seeing? I cannot reproduce: if I call your function with `[True]` (i.e. the worst case, where `num2bin index` returns `[]`), I simply get back the `x` that I put in `Node x iz de`, as I expect to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call this with `tail index`, hence eventually you reach the empty list, hence that explains why for the latter, if `length index == 1` fails, it will try to access `head index` and thus error.

But using `length` is not a good idea since it runs in *O(n)* with *n* the length of the list, and usually it is better to perform pattern matching on the list than to use `head` and `tail`, since then it is guaranteed that the list has a `head` and `tail`.

You can thus implement this as:

```
getAux :: SparseArray a -> [Bool] -> Value a
getAux (Node x _ _) [] = x
getAux (Node _ left right) (x:xs)
  | x = getAux right xs
  | otherwise = getAux left xs
```

By turining [**`-Wincomplete-patterns`** <sup>[Haskell-docs]</sup>](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/using-warnings.html#ghc-flag--Wincomplete-patterns) on for the compiler, it will warn you for patterns that the function does not cover. For example if your `SparseArray` has an extra data constructor, then these cases are not covered (yet).

Comment: If I am not mistaken if it always has a head and a tail it would enter an ampty loop

Comment: @biomaticstudios: no, an empty list will always error on both `head` and `tail` and are thus non-total. This is why some Haskell programmers consider these "unsafe" and avoid using these (as well as `length` since this can get stuck in an infinite loop for an infinite list, and takes *O(n)* time).

Comment: @biomaticstudios: this is also why using pattern matching is usually a better idea: the clause will only fire if the pattern matches, and so we are certain that the head `x` and the tail `xs` exists if it fires for `(x:xs)`. Furthermore the compiler can provide warnings about incomplete patterns: patterns of values that will fire no clause at all.

Comment: I'm not sure I buy this explanation. Presumably if `length index >= 1` to begin with, and `length index == 1` fails in some recursive call, then it is still the case that `length index >= 1`. Since they clam to call it with `num2bin index ++ [True]` as an argument, for which the length is definitely >= 1, I don't see how the unsafe partialness of `head` (or `tail`) would be realized.

Comment: @DanielWagner I hesitate to disagree with someone whose opinion I respect so highly, but personally I like to rely on the compiler to check I've covered all the cases rather than reasoning, so I'd prefer to pattern match with -Wincomplete-patterns on than use `head` or `tail` if I can.

Comment: @AndrewC I don't think anything you said disagrees with anything I said! In particular, I made no value judgments about one piece of code or another or of one coding practice or another; only of explanations of what caused an error.

Comment: @DanielWagner That's a relief!